# Does intersection of closure equal to closure of intersection, when locally finite.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

As known, if a family $\mathcal{S}$ is locally finite, then
$$
\cup_{S\in\mathcal{S}} \overline{S} = \overline{\cup_{S\in\mathcal{S}}S}.
$$
Is there a corresponding conclusion for the intersection case? That is if $\mathcal{S}$ is locally finite, does
$$
\cap_{S\in\mathcal{S}} \overline{S} = \overline{\cap_{S\in\mathcal{S}}S}
$$
hold?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Try $S_1=(0,1)$ and $S_2=(1,2)$.

Comment: ^ thank you very much